# How to remove only events handlers added in the instance?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

I have a jQuery plugin that is attaching event handlers on certain elements.

In the plugin's destroy method I wish to remove these event handlers, but only the ones that were added by that plugin instance.

if I do `.off('.myPlugin');` it may remove event handlers that were added by other plugin instances and I don't want that.

Is it possible what I'm asking?

Comment: Can you keep track of the events that you bind?

Comment: you mean store the event handler functions inside a array or something? yes. how do i pass that to off() ?

Comment: @thelolcat Loop over the array and call `.off("eventName", eventHandler)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery has event namespacing, that can be used for exactly this.

You namespace the events added, so they can be removed without removing other event handlers, so inside the plugin you'll add all event handlers like this

```
$( "p" ).on( 'click.pluginName', function(event) {
    // do stuff on click
});
```

And when you want to remove that click handler, and only that click handler, not other click handlers, you do

```
$( "p" ).off( 'click.pluginName');
```

This is how it's generally done in plugins.

documentation : [**jQuery event.namespace**](http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/)

---

If you need to identify each instance of the plugin, you could use a flag, counter or whatever.
Something like this would work

```
$.fn.plugin = function() {
    var self  = this,
        count = $.fn.plugin.counter++;

    $(this).on('click.pluginName' + count, function() {
        // do stuff on click
    });

    this.destroy = function() {
        self.off('click.pluginName' + count)
    }

}

$.fn.plugin.counter = 0;
```

---

or another variation

```
$.fn.plugin = function(arg) {
    if (arg == 'destroy') {

        var count = $(this).data('count');
        $(this).off('click.pluginName' + count);

    }else{

        var count = $.fn.plugin.counter++;

        $(this).data('count', count).on('click.pluginName' + count, function() {
            alert('clicked')
        });
    }

    return this;
}

$.fn.plugin.counter = 0;
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5AZjA/)

Comment: I am using namespace, but all instances have the same namespace :|

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think to do that is to generate a GUID for each instance of that plugin and then concatenate that to your plugin name when binding and unbinding events.